# File overwrite error 22 in qgis graphical modeler while running modeler more than once

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

File overwrite error 22 'invalid file' in qgis graphical modeler while running modeler more than once, when system is restarted in there is no temporary file in qgis workspace then model runs fine and produces output, but when run again gives error 22[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be a bug report rather than a question on StackExchange.